# How to programatically find all my AWS account's limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a way to see all our AWS account limits (e.g. maximum number of buckets in each region, maximum number of ELB's etc) in one location.

I found the page at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html, but this lists only the default limits. It won't tell me our limits after some of them were raised upon our request.

I also found `aws ec2 describe-account-attributes`, for instance, but this gives only EC2-related limits.

Comment: That has been a big problem for me in the past. I've always had to contact them regarding limits, that I hit by accident. I hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to get all the service limits in a simple manner at the moment. However, some of the services support this in their respective CLIs/SDKs which there is an open source project available that are trying to consolidate this into one CLI tool. The [awslimitchecker](https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker). Maybe that could make life easier for you? :)

Comment: This is as close at it gets to a useful answer.